# ViewModel not keeping data on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ListBox implemented as below.

```
    @if (Model.SelectListVendorBranchSearched != null )
                {
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedVendorBranchLeft, Model.SelectListVendorBranchSearched, new {@class="listbox", @size ="10" })
}
```

But when the form is posted back the viewModel object does not have the original Data Source that the list was bound to. But it has the selected items posted back.

Is that the right behavior?

Let me try to explain what I am trying to achive.

I am trying to implement the following in ASP.NET MVC.

I have a search functionality that populates a list box say List box A. Now I need to select some items in the List Box A and move the items to another List Box say List Box B. Then do another search that refreshes the List Box A with fresh results. Then again select some more items in the List Box A and append to the items already in List Box B. In the end get the items in the List Box B and save it to DB. How can I do this without any JavaScript?

Comment: Look at the resulting HTML, and look at the serialized form that gets submitted to the server. There's no data source submitted, right? You'll need to rewire it up in your controller. Or better yet, why do you need a data source in your view?

Comment: But I have a DropDown implememted on the view similarly.  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedMergeFile, Model.MergeFileList), The data source which is MergeFileList is posted back to the controller. Why is it different in ListBox and DropDown?

Comment: If you post the code for the controller, we can help you better.

Comment: Yes, its the default behavior. A `<select multiple>` only posts back and array of its selected values. You do not and should not be generating form controls for each proeprty of each `SelectListItem` in the view (and regarding your previous comment - there is no difference between `ListBoxFor()` and `DropDownListFor()` - the 'data source is never posted back)